# How do I modify a jQuery statment to act on li element class instead of anchor tag class?

Tags: jquery, navigation

Due to constraints beyond the scope of this post, I need to modify some functioning jQuery to work based on the class of a list element rather than the class of an anchor tag.

Here is the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#sub-nav > ul > li')
        .children('a.drop').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).siblings('ul').toggle("slow");
            return false;
        }).end()
        .children('ul').hide();
}); 
</script>
```

and it worked great on this html:

```
<div id="subContent">
<ul>
<li><a href="nikon.html">Nikon</a></li>

<li class="cameras"><a href="#" class="drop">Cameras</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="nikon-d3x.html">Nikon D3x</a></li>
<li><a href="nikon-d3s.html">Nikon D3s</a></li>
<li><a href="nikon-d700.html">Nikon D700</a></li>
<li><a href="nikon-d300s.html">Nikon D300s</a></li>      
</ul>
</li>

<li class="lenses"><a href="#" class="drop">Lenses</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="24-70.html">Nikkor 24-70 f2.8</a></li>
<li><a href="80-200.aspx">Nikkor 80-200 f2.8</a></li> 
<li><a href="300.html">Nikkor 300 f2.8</a></li>
<li><a href="50.html">Nikkor 50 f1.4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="bags"><a href="#" class="drop">Bags</a>
<ul>
<li><a  href="bag1.html">Small Bag</a></li>
<li><a href="bag2.html">Medium Bag</a></li>
<li><a href="bag3.html">Large Ba</a></li>
</ul>
</li> 
<li><a href="#" class="drop">Memory Cards</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

However, I need to change the parent list element, moving the class="drop" from the `<a>` to the `<li>`:

Original: `<li class="cameras"><a href="#" class="drop">Cameras</a>`

New: `<li class="cameras drop"><a href="#">Cameras</a>`

How would I modify the jQuery to accommodate this change? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5ChC/) works the same as your provided code with the modification.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sub-nav > ul > li.drop > a:first-child').mouseenter(function{...
```

EDIT: Use `:first-child` instead of `:first`.

Comment: Hi Rocket. This works pretty good on the sample provided but only on the first list item: http://www.rouviere.com/nav/. If you mouse over the other ones, like lenses, nothing happens.

Comment: @fmz: My bad, `:first` should be `:first-child`.